# Can a lightsaber kill its owner?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber

In all of the *Star Wars* movies, a Jedi's main weapon is the lightsaber. We can see them with many different colors.

So my question is, can the owner of a lightsaber be killed by it?

Comment: Not according to Professor Proton's Force Ghost.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking whether a lightsaber owner is immune to their own saber?

Comment: Lightsabers don't kill people.

Comment: Lightsabers don't kill people, Sith kill people.

Comment: Lightsabers don't kill. People with lighsabers kill.

Comment: Perhaps if we had a robust 2000 day waiting period.

Comment: If the owner of a lightsaber could not be killed by a lightsaber, then literally every lightsaber fight in existence would be useless.

Comment: What prompted you to ask this question? Why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: A lightsaber is just like a sword. It can kill its owner just like a sword can kill its owner in real life. There is nothing intrinsically special about it in relationship to its owner in regards to sentience or being opposed to the death of its creator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most obvious example I can think of is in *Revenge of the Sith* when Anakin kills Count Dooku using his own lightsaber and Dooku's to chop his head off as mentioned in [Shreedhar's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/225631/58193).

However, if you want an example of a Jedi killing themselves with their own lightsaber, and so not someone else killing them with it, we have a Legends example. In the story "The Duty" from the comic *Star Wars Tales 12* Gira commits suicide with his own lightsaber after being bested by Darth Vader.

[image: Gira commits suicide]

Answer (score 7):

### The answer is, unsurprisingly, Yes!

---

A lightsaber is simply a weapon thus it can be used to kill even its owner. The one instance that I remember happening *on-screen* is the murder of Count Dooku by Anakin.

In *Revenge of the Sith*, Anakin overpowers Dooku severing his hands and when Palpatine then tells Anakin to execute Dooku on the spot, he does so without the slightest of hesitation. There, Anakin uses two lightsabers: his and Dooku's. You can watch it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xu4hbGCNwCI).

---

Another instance, off-screen (specifically, from a deleted scene) is the death of the Jedi master Shaak Ti. In *Revenge of the Sith*, Shaak Ti is captured by General Grievous and killed in front of Obi-Wan and Anakin (video [here](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4woos), thanks @Valorum). However, I am not sure if the lightsaber that Grievous used belonged to Shaak Ti.

Comment: While the answer is, of course, correct, I am not sure if the Dooku example is valid. Anakin had two swords so the Dooku would be dead even without using Dooku's sword.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In [*The Force Unleashed*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Force_Unleashed_(novel)) book, Starkiller killed a Jedi with his own lightsaber

Comment: I'm not positive, but I'm pretty sure this is Legends, right?  You should note that in your answer, since canon answers are preferable.

Comment: Will do next time